# Letters not hit by light or causing shadows?

Tags: image

Ive uploaded a screen shot of my session, where hopefully you can see the word i've next to a cube. I have a spot lamp above which can been seen hitting the cube. But the letters arnt affected in anyway. I was hoping the light would hit the letters and cast a shadow? Hope can I make this happen?

Many thanks,

J[image]

[image]

here's link to the program, it's a new one with a similar problem. Theres a falling man but his shadows is square. Theres no material attached to the image? here's a screenshot: [image]

Comment: do the letters have a black material?

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your letters are parallel to the light rays and therefore not lighted. Rotate the light or letters so that the the letters' surface is hit by light.